# How do I convert this mechanical system into a mechanical network?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, systems-engineering

[image]

How do I convert this into a mechanical network? like a circuit network.

my attempted work is this:

[image]

is this schematic correct?

Comment: So similar to [this page](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Analogs/ElectricalMechanicalAnalogs.html)?

Comment: not necessarily. the components should not be changed.

Comment: Than I am not sure what you mean, because I would think that this is already a mechanical network. The only thing that you could change is to also connect B and K3 to the wall on the left (since they are both stationary, only the initial lengths change).

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i will edit my post and attach my attempted work.

Comment: That makes things a lot more clear (I am just not used to using this kind of representation). But it seems to be correct.

Comment: i am doubting my answer because I am not sure if M1, M2, and K2 shoud be connected to the ground (reference).

Comment: @Dan i dont think M1M2 and K2should be connected to the ground.

Comment: @joojaa can you show me where to connect them instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have is correct, provided the friction and spring constants are inverses.

I am more comfortable with the force-voltage analogy and would create the equivalent one as follows.

[image]